# Websocket Handshake failed with Faye Server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, faye

In my Project, I am using the faye Server for publishing notifications. but when I tried to create a client through **javascript** it is throwing the following error.

```
var client = new Faye.Client('https://uname-faye-server.herokuapp.com/faye');

WebSocket connection to 'wss://uname-faye-server.herokuapp.com/faye' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Have you tried putting the port number at the end of the URI?